# MagicalRecord date parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, magicalrecord

I've got a date in the following format:

`2013-05-04T05:07:09+00:00`

I'm using MagicalRecord to map the NSDate automatically. As far as I can see the above date format should comply with MagicalRecord's default date format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`.

I have tried with a custom `dateFormat` entry in the attribute's user info (see [this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/)):

`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+Z`, `yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ss Z`, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+'Z`

but none of them work in order to have it parse the date properly and it always returns `nil` regardless of setting a custom `dateFormat` or using MagicalRecord's default format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at your string:

```
2013-05-04T05:07:09+00:00
```

This is:

1. four digit year
2. hyphen
3. zero-padded month
4. hyphen
5. zero-padded day of month
6. 'T' character
7. zero-padded hour
8. ':' character
9. zero-padded minute
10. ':' character
11. zero-padded second
12. timezone (with direction from GMT and a separating colon)

Thus, according to [the date format specifiers documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns), the pattern you'd want is:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

Also, be sure to use the `en_US_POSIX` locale with the `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: You've been a minute faster than me :) +1

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I was under the impression just one Z was needed for 00:00 according to the specification, so that was my issue. Thanks very much for your prompt reply!

Comment: @runmad `Z` would be for `+0000`.  Since you've got the `:` in there, you need `ZZZZZ` :)

Comment: Ah, well that makes it a bit confusing when : can be written elsewhere but in this case it's a Z :) Thanks again :)